# IllegalArgumentException while taking a screen shot of a custom view

Tags: android, view, screenshot

While trying to make a screen shot of a custom view,I got the `IllegalArgumentException : width and height must be >0`. Here is what I wrote :

```
bitmap = loadBitmapFromView(v1);//v1 the custom view I want to picture.
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v) {
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap( v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);                
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
v.layout(0, 0, v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height);
v.draw(c);
return b;
}
```

The line in which there is the exception : `Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap( v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);`
Of course the screen shot code is executed after the view is showed,on the next_act button code

Comment: Where is this code?  In which method?  Where do you call it from?

Comment: The code is above,the line to call and the method

Comment: No.  Where is this code in your program?  in onCreate(), in a custom method?  How is the code called?

Answer (score 0):

The width and height of `LayoutParams` can be a constant such as `FILL_PARENT`, and they are negative numbers.

To get the view's measured dimensions you can use:

```
v.getMeasuredWidth() and v.getMeasuredHeight()
```

However, it depends on what you're after, and whether the view has been measured.

It would probably make more sense to wait until the view has been drawn, before taking the screenshot ;-) But you'd need to explain more about your use case.

Comment: i already tried this : v.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)); 
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap( v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
but it's the same exception

Comment: Have you tried passing some values to v.measure(). E.g. display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); v.measure(display.getWidth(), display.getHeight());

Comment: when i write this : 
Display display =getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
i got an error in which eclipse tell me to rename the getWindowManager

Comment: You'd need a context, such as context.getWindowManager()

Comment: i added onMesure to my custom view class but i got the same exception